# MVC3 EF 4.1 Include Condition Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4

Apologies if this has been asked before as I am learning EF 4.1 and LINQ, I needed an expert opinion. 
I have a viewmodel called HomeIndexData. My code looks something like the following:

string _categoryIDs = "100,101,102,103,104";

List < int > CategoryIDs = _categoryIDs.Split(',').Select(t => int.Parse(t));

Then I got the following view model:

```
public class HomeIndexData
{

    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Country> Countries { get; set; }    

}
```

At the moment, in my Controller I have the following code -

```
HomeIndexData viewModel = new HomeIndexData
            {

                     Genres = db.Genres
                              .Include(i => i.Categories.Where(i => CategoryIDs.Contains(i.CategoryId)))
                              .Include("Categories.SubCategories")
                              .OrderBy(g => g.DisplaySequence),
                  Countries = db.countries            

            };
```

But I am getting error :

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
```

for the following line :

```
     .Include(i => i.Categories.Where(i => CategoryIDs.Contains(i.CategoryId)))
```

Could you please put me to the right direction how can I write the lamda expression.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? All of those Categories will be present and you can limit them afterward with Genres.Categories.Where(<<predicate>>)

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't support complex expressions in the Include extension at this point, only simple property getters. If you feel this is an important enhancement scenario for EF, consider voting for it at http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015345-allow-filtering-for-include-extension-method.

For now, your best option is to project your filter in the Select clause, but that gets tricky with a generic repository.